Does equality check for floats in python check against machine epsilon tolerances?
I'm a bit confused about the precision on floats in python and equality checks.
e.g.,
15 + 1e-16 == 15

evaluates to true b/c 1e-16 is < machine epsilon for fp64.
and
15 + 1e-15 == 15

evaluates false because 1e-15 > machine epsilon for fp64.
But when I do sys.getsizeof(15 + 1e-16), I get 24 bytes, i.e., fp192, which if it were true, would mean 15 + 1e-16 == 15 would evaluate false since machine epsilon for fp192 is surely << 1e-16.
I always thought == is checking whether the LHS is within +/- of machine epsilon for the respective type.
To add to my confusion, I checked:
1e-323 == 0 # evaluates false
1e-324 == 0 # evaluates true
sys.getsizeof(1e-323) # gives 24 bytes

I don't understand the bound on this.

First, sys.getsizeof gives the in-memory size of an object, which may include some overhead; it's not the same as, say, sizeof in C.  So that size of 24 does not imply you're actually dealing with 192-bit extended-precision floating point.  And then, to your main question, most languages (Python included) implement == as strict equality.  If you want an approximate equality test, you're often on your own. (But see https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/ .)

Also, "machine epsilon" is the absolute precision near 1.0.  For numbers near 16, the effective epsilon will be 8 or 16 times that.

@SteveSummit "implement == as strict equality" ah I see, but strict equality is just checking that bit-by-bit gives equality right? I actually thought this was equivalent to checking against epsilon tolerances?

What's compared bit-for-bit is the IEEE754 double-precision value (all 64 bits of it), and the comparison is for exact equality.  That thing 1e-324 you typed doesn't get compared at all — an early stage off the Python interpreter translates the characters 1 e - 3 2 4 into the closest IEEE754 double-precision value, and it's that value that ends up getting compared.  And it turns out that in the case of 1e-324, the closest IEEE754 double-precision value is 0.0.

"strict equality is just checking that bit-by-bit gives equality right?" --> No.  -0.0 == +0.0 is true, yet have different bit patterns. a == a is usually false when a is a not-a-number, yet a and a have the same bit pattern..

Comparison of all numeric types (including floats) is exact in Python. Hardware precision has nothing to do with it.
getsizeof() is returning the size of the Python object, which includes things like bytes for a pointer to the object's type object, and the reference count. The actual data for a float occupies 8 bytes on almost all current machines, a small part of it.

When you say "exact" you mean exact in the bit representation right and not in the mathematical sense?

Both. Comparison only sees the bit representations. It's the arithmetic operations (+, -, *, ...) that may lose information to rounding. Comparisons take their inputs at face value, and do exact comparison on the presumed-exact comparands.

I see, what about in the case of 1e-324 == 0? Clearly this is not a mathematical equivalence, and equivalent in code due to limitations on precisoin in hardware?

The equality comparison is still exact - it's always exact ;-) It's the literal 1e-324 all on its own, in isolation, that lost information to rounding. It's too small for your HW to represent, so rounds to exactly 0, the closest number your HW can represent.

And if it's not clear, the what happens is that the string 1e-324 you type in your Python program gets more or less immediately converted into 0.0, and then 0.0 is equal to 0.  That is, while parsing your code 1e-324 gets translated into 0, and then later, while evaluating the expression, the expression evaluator finds itself being asked to compare 0.0 and 0.0.

@SteveSummit Right I do understand it gets converted to 0. The gap in my understanding is I didn't know the numerical threshold in which the value gets converted to 0. For as long as I remember, I had always thought that numerical threshold was machine eps (~2.2e-16 for double precision IIRC), but I now see that I really doesn't have anything to do with this

~2.2e-16 is the smallest power of 2 that, when added to 1.0, isn't entirely lost to nearest/even rounding. It's equal to math.ulp(1.0), the power-of-2 weight of 1.0's least-significant representable bit. 1.0 + math.ulp(1.0) is greater than 1, but 1.0 + math.ulp(1.0) / 2 is exactly 1.0.`

So 2.2e-16 is the absolute precision over the range (the binade) from 1.0 to 2.  From 2.0 to 4, it's twice that.  From 0.5 to 1, it's half that.  And down near the minimum double-precision value (which is what we care about here), it's 2⁻¹⁰²² of that, or about 5e-324.  So that's why 1e-323 was measurably different from 0, but 1e-324 was not.  (And therefore epsilon does have everything to do with it, as long as you look at it — i.e. scale it — correctly.)
